# Finding optimal input variabels for a function (Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, scipy-optimize

I have a piece of code that does a thing. In that code I have multiple variabels that I can change with the goal to get the best possible end result.

```
inputVariable1 = [-1,-2,0,1,2]              # All the possible input variablels in can go over
inputVariable2 = [-3,-1,-2,0,1,2,3]
inputVariable3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def Function(inputVariable1,inputVariable2,inputVariable3):

    # doing some stuff with those variabels, in this simplified case I want to find the biggest 
    # possible sum of those numbers (real code is a bit more complex)

    endResult = inputVariable1 + inputVariable2 + inputVariable3

    return endResult
```

Thus I would like to check every possible combination of those inputVariabels (I have 20 in my code and the codes takes 10 seconds each time to calculate) and find the one that can produce the best result or that reaches at least a minimum result.

e.g. test: Function(-1,-3,0), Function(-2,-3,0),...,Function(2,3,9),Function(2,3,10)
But looping through every possible combination seems really inefficient, is there a better solution?

I have been looking around and could really find anything that I could use, or understand (still learning).

I have looked at loops and such, but with 8 variabels with each 6 possible values to choose from it would take approximately 194 days to calculate each possibility and I think and hope that could be done more efficiently.

Thx in advance.

Edit 1:
A bunch of things are calculated and each variable represents the weight that calculation will have, the sum of those variabels will then determine if a certain action will be performed or not.

e.g.

```
while i in range(0,len(data)):
     if x[i] > y[i]:
          sum += inputVariable1
     if x[i] < z[i]:
          sum += inputVariable2
     ...

      if sum > 5:
         doAction()
      else:
         doOtherAction()
```

Comment: Multi processing should, like the answer below, really help your cause. That said, if you actually need the result of all the possible input variables there's nothing you can do except for just calculating them all. Maybe you could try and explain what you're trying to accomplish. It might be that there are smarter solutions out there for your use case. Currently it's too generic to give an in depth thought on your problem.

Comment: A bunch of things are calculated and each variable represents the weight that calculation will have, the sum of those variabels will then determine if a certain action will be performed or not.

e.g.
```
while i in range(0,len(data)):
     if x[i] > y[i]:
          sum += inputVariable1
     if x[i] < z[i]:
          sum += inputVariable2
     ...

      if sum > 5:
         doAction()
      else:
         doOtherAction()

```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use something similar to an optimizer used in AI, which basically means you try one, record the result, then try another one, and see how it changes. If the second one is better and you, for example, made variable 1 a larger number, you can keep doing that. The same for all the other variables, until you find the local minimum. This might not find it perfectly, but normally it will, especially with as little parameters as you have I doubt it should be a problem. An easier solution would be to use either Threads or multiprocessing to speed the process of bruteforce up

Comment: Thx, but the example above is heavily simplified, the real code uses around 20 inputvariabels that can be selected out of a couple of values. I already spend a couple of days finding better results manually but it is a very tedious and slow process. But multiprocessing or similar could be a good thing to try.